# Pyttsx3 works in console but not script. Doesn't give any output on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I've encountered something strange with Python in Ubuntu. Tried this on several machines now.

If I run this code in the console, line by line, then it outputs a text.mp3 file, as expected.

However, if I put the code in script.py and run that by doing python3 script.py then I don't get any file saved at all.

Does anyone have any clue why this is? The script is executing, if I put print("test") in the script then I am getting output from that. I'm just not getting any file saved.

Code

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")[0]
engine.setProperty('voice', voices)
text = 'Your Text'
engine.save_to_file(text, 'text.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Works for me. I had to install `libespeak-dev` using apt-get, though.

Comment: Nope, no errors, no nothing. Do you get a file running that code on Ubuntu? What version? @H.Rittich

Comment: I used Debian Bullseye. What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: @H.Rittich tried on 20.04 and 18.04 LTS

Comment: I have just setup a Ubuntu 18.04 container. A have run `apt-get install ffmpeg libespeak-dev` and `pip3 install pyttsx3`, to install the dependencies. Running your script works. The file `text.mp3` is generated. Have you tried to upgrade pyttsx3 using pip?

Comment: @H.Rittich yep everything upgraded. I've tried running this on three different Ubuntu VPS'es now and they all failed. Truly baffled that it works for you! Are you running a physical machine or a VPS/cloud solution?

Comment: I ran an Ubuntu 18.04 container (podman) on my machine. Since you are running remotly, maybe it is something mundane. Before running your code could you use `cat` to check that the file actually contains the code you think it does? Otherwise, you can run your code using `strace` to see what it does.

Comment: @H.Rittich https://i.imgur.com/TNm21tJ.png any ideas? I'm baffled!

Comment: Interesting. Could you add a print statement after every statement that prints the result of the statement?